# In R, how do I check a vector for values and then increment a different variable n for every value present?

Tags: r, vector

I am new to R! I would like to know how to check a vector for values greater than 1.96 and then increment a variable n by 1 for every value greater than 1.96. I know an example in C++ for an array

```
for(i<101)
{
   if(samplespace[i]>1.96)
   n=n+1;
}
```

Now I just need to know how to do the same thing with a vector in R. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe just `sum(samplespace > 1.96)`?

Comment: I agree with joran's suggestion. By the way, the rules for writing an iterator (the first clause after `for`) can be found in the docs. Type `?\`for\``

Comment: It worked! Thank you!